# Add data to return of all actions in a Symfony controller

Tags: symfony, render, symfony-2.1

I have a controller in a Symfony 2.1 application, let's just call it `FooController` in the `BarBundle`. This controller has a lot of actions `fooAction`, `barAction`, `bazAction` and a few more.

All of them have something in common. They're displaying in some part's the same data in the view, not in all, so I can't just use one action with the type as parameter. I would like to add the data that has to be passed to the view in one central place, otherwise, it just wouldn't be dry.

Bad (in my opinion):

```
public function fooAction() {
    // ...
    return $this->render('BarBundle:Foo:foo.html.twig', array('foo' => 'Foo Data', 'data' => $this->getTheDataThatIsNeededInEveryAction()));
}
public function barAction() {
    // ...
    return $this->render('BarBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig', array('bar' => 'Bar Data', 'data' => $this->getTheDataThatIsNeededInEveryAction()));
}
public function bazAction() {
    // ...
    return $this->render('BarBundle:Foo:baz.html.twig', array('baz' => 'Baz Data', 'data' => $this->getTheDataThatIsNeededInEveryAction()));
}
```

What I'm wondering now, is, what would be the "Good" way? Is there like a `finished` function in the parent controller that is called just before sending the data to the view, where I could add that data to the response object?

Another possibility would be, to create an event listener, but I think that would be a waste of resources.

A third option would be to use the render function like `{% render url('latest_articles', { 'max': 3 }) %}`
I know nowadays it's `{{ render(controller(..)) }}` but I'm stuck with Symfony 2.1 in with this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create your own base controller, and have all other controller extend it. Your base controller would override the `render` function of the `Controller` class from symfony framework

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    // override render method
    protected function render($template, $data)
    {
        $commonData = [];// get data from wherever you need
        parent::render($template, $data + $commonData);
    }
}
```

Then in your other controllers

```
class MyAnotherController extends BaseController
{
    public function fooAction() {
    // ...
    return $this->render('BarBundle:Foo:foo.html.twig', array('foo' => 'Foo Data'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of options

```
public function commonAction($type) {
     // ...
     return $this->render('BarBundle:Foo:'.$type.'.html.twig', array('data' => $this->getTheDataThatIsNeededInEveryAction()));
}
```

where `$type` would be   bar, foo or baz

Comment: Unfortunately, the functions aren't that simple, they have to return different data for each action, I'll add that to the question.