# Add data return in all actions with @Template annotation

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I need to return default data in all actions in my Symfony project.
For example search form in side bar, viewers counter etc...

So i need to return some default data in all actions

```
return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'short_search' => $shortSearch->createView(),
);
```

I found [Add data to return of all actions in a Symfony controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692035/add-data-to-return-of-all-actions-in-a-symfony-controller) solution, but it fails when I'm using `@Template` annotation.

Of course i can call `render` function from twig, but it seems like it's not fast and good idea.

What component I should override in this case???

Comment: And you'll include on every controller template the sidebar or set data to base template, is it better idea? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html) section of the Symfony Best Practices document advises against using the `@Template()` annotation, so the easy fix to your problem would be to simply not use `@Template()`.

The reason overriding the base Controller's render method doesn't work is because you're not actually calling it, and neither is the framework. Instead, the [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle @Template annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html) works by installing an event listener for `KernelEvents::VIEW` (`kernel.view`) and (after having used a different event to guess the template name, if necessary), directly uses the templating service to render the response.

In the generic case, what you can do instead is install an event listener on `kernel.view` with a higher priority, and using the `GetResponseForControllerResultEvent` event provided to add in your parameters. This event listener might look something like

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForControllerResultEvent;

public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
{
    $parameters = $event->getControllerResult();

    //modify parameters

    $event->setControllerResult($parameters);
}
```

with whatever services necessary to get the additional parameters passed in via dependency injection. You may also want to look at the implementation for [@Template's TemplateListener](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/TemplateListener.php) for reference.

The [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html) has more information on how to set up event listeners.

In your specific case, you're probably going to be generating your `$form` and `$shortSearch` entirely from within that event handler, so at the least, your event handler is going to need at least the form service injected.

In my opinion, this is all largely more trouble than it's worth, and it would be better to just remove the @Template annotation instead. (As a bonus, you'll get a minor performance boost, especially if you [disable the annotations entirely](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#configuration), because you won't have the overhead of calling those event listeners on every request.)

Comment: Thank you very much for such complex and massive answer. I will read Best Practices section.