# Getting the same data in each controller function

Tags: php, symfony

I have session where I handle userID when user log in.

In each controller function If user is logged in I must download data(from db) about user and send it to view.

**Effect:**
In each function I have at least ~4 lines of the same code.

**Question**: Is there another simpler way to do that? (without code overflow)

//Edit

I use something like this in each controller:

```
$variables = array();
$defaultModel = new DefaultModel($em->getRepository('AppBundle:Users'), new Session());
$variables['user'] = $defaultModel->getUserHandle()->getBaseUserData();
//...
return $this->render('UbBundle:Account:Logout.html.twig', $variables);
```

Comment: Off topic but new Session() in a Symfony controller is probably not doing what you expect.  In any event, setup a controller listener per: http://symfony.com/doc/3.2/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to solve this. As long as you do not provide any more information about your controller functions, e.g. how you create the response or render the view I can only guess.

A simple solution would be to use [your own base controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692035/add-data-to-return-of-all-actions-in-a-symfony-controller):

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    // override render method
    protected function render($template, $data)
    {
        // get your user data from db
        $userData = [];

        parent::render($template, array_merge( $userData, $data );
    }
}
```

and let your controllers extend from the `BaseController`:

```
class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function fooAction() {

        // call the render function in your BaseController which adds user data to the view params     
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Bar:bar.html.twig', array('bar' => 'Hello World!'));

    }
}
```

If you do not like that approach you could also create your own event listener / subscriber to hook into the process, e.g. listen for [kernel.view](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-view-event), [kernel.response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-response-event) event or [kernel.controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-controller-event)
 event to manipulate the controller process using [before or after filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)

Comment: Could you give example, how to do the same using events? Then I will not have to override render method in each controller

Comment: Yes, I can give you an example, but I would need some more information how a typical action and their response in your controller looks like. Do you use render(), renderView() or make use of the @View() annotation, etc.

Comment: I edited my question -> in each controller I need session and doctrine then push it to function with getting data from db and push to render view.

I only want to know how to get doctrine and session handle in this event , push example data to render and the rest I will do alone

Comment: btw, if you use your own `BaseController` class you only override the render function once. What you need to change is the class your controllers are extending. So 'EachController extends Controller` becomes `EachController extends BaseController`. 

You are using `render()` which will return a `Response` object, so the `kernel.view` event never gets dispatched. You need to return an array to to  make use of a custom event subscriber and push your data to the view. Otherwise you can follow some of the other suggestions and e.g. create a gobal twig var `user`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a private method or a service that does the logic for you, and then call it from the 4 places.

Answer (score 0):

You can [access current authenticated user](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/app_variable.html) directly from a twig template using `app.user` variable.

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a twig extension, that has a function to do this? You can call it in your view layer without code duplication and altering all your controllers.

Answer (score -1):

You could put these 4 lines of code in a method that would be called on the controller constructor.

Comment: Have you ever tried to do this?  You might be surprised that you don't have access to the container in the constructor when using the standard framework controller.